# Python 3 Multiprocessing Array initialization randomly hangs

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, python-multiprocessing

TL;DR: Multiprocessing shared arrays work fine using Python 2, but they randomly hang (several seconds) using Python 3. I'm running the code on a RPi3.

I'm writing code for video capture on a Raspberry Pi 3 and I need to have 2 video buffers of 256 frames which are alternated. While one buffer is being filled, the other is being processed in another thread.

I've been successfully doing this for years with Python 2, but recently I ported everything to Python 3. Then I noticed a lot of frames are being dropped, seemingly randomly.

Here is the code I'm using for testing:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

import numpy as np

import time
import multiprocessing
import ctypes



class BufferedCapture(multiprocessing.Process):


    running = False

    def __init__(self, array1, array2):

        super(BufferedCapture, self).__init__()

        self.array1 = array1

        self.array2 = array2



    def startCapture(self):
        """ Start capture using the specified camera.

        """

        self.exit = multiprocessing.Event()
        self.start()



    def stopCapture(self):
        """ Stop capture.
        """

        self.exit.set()
        self.join()


    def run(self):

        assignment_times = []
        for i in range(256):

            print(i)

            # Assign arrays to video frames (in this case, use placeholder values)

            t1 = time.time()
            self.array1[i, :1200, :700] = np.ones((1200, 700), dtype=np.uint8)*3
            assignment_times.append(time.time() - t1)

            t1 = time.time()
            self.array2[i, :1200, :700] = np.ones((1200, 700), dtype=np.uint8)*5
            assignment_times.append(time.time() - t1)


        print('Max assignment time:', max(assignment_times))
        print('Avg assignemnt time:', sum(assignment_times)/len(assignment_times))





if __name__ == "__main__":


    import multiprocessing.sharedctypes

    width = 1280
    height = 720

    array_pad = 1

    # Init shared arrays
    array_size = 256*(width + array_pad)*(height + array_pad)

    array1_ctypes = multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawArray(ctypes.c_uint8, array_size)
    array1 = np.frombuffer(array1_ctypes, dtype=np.uint8, count=array_size)
    array1.shape = (256, width + array_pad, height + array_pad)

    array2_ctypes = multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawArray(ctypes.c_uint8, array_size)
    array2 = np.frombuffer(array2_ctypes, dtype=np.uint8, count=array_size)
    array2.shape = (256, width + array_pad, height + array_pad)


    bc = BufferedCapture(array1, array2)

    print('Starting')
    # Start buffered capture
    bc.startCapture()

    print('Stopping')
    bc.stopCapture()

    print(array1)
    print('_________________')
    print(array2)
```

After running the code with Python 2.7, this is was it reports:

```
Max assignment time: 0.0120410919189
Avg assignment time: 0.0102647687308
```

Everything is fine.

On the other hand, here is what I get with Python 3.6:

```
Max assignment time: 5.458962678909302
Avg assignment time: 0.07329284632578492
```

Upon futher analysis I have noticed the array assignment just randomly hangs, while is most cases it's reasonably fast, although not as fast as with Python 2.

I have also noticed that it takes a very long time (~10s) to initilize the arrays at the beginning with Python 3, while it's basically instantaneous with Python 2.

I am completely stumped by this, does anyone have any clue what's going on here?

Thanks!

P.S.
This code is a part of my low-cost meteor camera project, here's the GitHub repo if anyone is interested: https://github.com/CroatianMeteorNetwork/RMS

**UPDATE:**

I have tested this on my laptop running Linux Mint 18.1, and both Python 2 and 3 are running equally fast. This is a Raspberry Pi-specific problem.